# MS SQL Database data to .aspx page

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm a Front-end developer and I'm currently working on a project that I need to take data from MS SQL Database and display the data on the .aspx page using HTML5. C# is used on the .aspx pages, if that helps any.

I really don't know where to begin. I've tried doing some research,but have not been successful. Is there a server-side method that I need to make the connection? Any direction or advise would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: What software are you using? Visual Studio? If so you can just create a data connection to the MS SQL database (assuming you have the credentials...) then pretty much drag and drop tables to an aspx page in VS.

Comment: Yes I'm using Visual Studio. If I drag the tables to the aspx page can i mark it up with HTML and CSS?

Comment: You could but dragging and dropping a table is an extremely basic example. I would recommend watching a C# or ASP.NET course on www.lynda.com or even searching google for more information on SQL Datasources and gridviews

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One good tool for asp.net is Entity Framework.

As quoted by Microsoft: "Entity Framework is Microsoft’s recommended data access technology for new applications".

Have a look: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ef.aspx

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what the deployment server has running.  Does the deployment server support .NET 4.5 or only .NET 2.0?

Like the previous answer, I like Entity Framework, but it really depends on what technologies are available based on your deployment server (hosting environment).